# Add pre link to all links in a div, On link click execute function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=microsoftwebpro.com&callback=?', function(data){
  $('#output').html(data.contents);
});
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

I have the following code, and basically what I'm trying to do is prepend the link http://anyorigin.com/get?url=thislinkisinhtml.com&callback=? to every link.
The next thing I would like to do is on a link click is to call the above script and have it change the div "output". Basically so that it runs itself on one page in the div and won't be affected by link clicks.

Comment: Please show example and expected results. Also show what you have tried. The idea here is to help resolve code issues...not write code from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will edit all the links on the page.

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', 'http://anyorigin.com/get?url='+$(this).attr('href')+'&callback=?');
});
```

The code below will be called on every link click.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $.getJSON($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
        $('#output').html(data.contents);
    });
});
```

Comment: Since theres "&callback= at the end would the code be split like so?
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', 'http://anyorigin.com/get?url=thislinkisinhtml.com'+$(this).attr('href')+'&callback=');
});

Comment: @CameronGilbert you really should look into coding before asking

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify what you mean?  For example, if a link on the page had an href of `https://google.com`, after the first piece of code ran, the href would be `http://anyorigin.com/get?url=thislinkisinhtml.com&callback=https://google.com`.  The JSON call would be made to that link.  You can split it on the ampersand or pull in the parameters on the server.

Comment: No where thislinkisinhtml.com needs to be replaced by google.com

Comment: Okay, then you don't want to simply prepend the first href.  I've edited my answer to give you what you wanted.